# Laravel: Get count of total number of pass and fail results from mysql

Tags: mysql, graph, laravel-5.6

i'm stuck in this problem. i have a table in database which os_flash_result which can be either PASS or FAIl.
i have to display the number of fail and pass result in the form of graph with date.

My table structure and data is as follows:

```
mysql> select * from mobile_prod_pograms;
+----+-----------+-----------------+------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | device_id | os_flash_result | action                 | station | build_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+-----------------+------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  2 | 1         | FAIL            | Mobile Production Prog |       1 | mp1      | 2018-09-27 00:00:00 | 2018-09-27 00:00:00 |
| 19 | 1         | PASS            | Mobile Production Prog |       1 | mp1      | 2018-09-27 00:00:00 | 2018-09-27 00:00:00 |
| 20 | 1         | PASS            | Mobile Production Prog |       1 | mp1      | 2018-09-27 00:00:00 | 2018-09-27 00:00:00 |
+----+-----------+-----------------+------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i'm using laravel so i have wirtten the following query to get Count of PASS results.

```
$mobile_chart_query =  DB::table('mobile_prod_pograms')
            ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
            ->where('os_flash_result','=','PASS')
            ->where('created_at','>=','2018-09-17')
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->get();
```

The above Query is working fine.
but i want to get failure and pass results count in a single query with date.How can i achieve that?
Any help will be Appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation:

```
$mobile_chart_query =  DB::table("mobile_prod_pograms")
    ->select(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) AS date"),
             DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN os_flash_result = 'PASS' THEN 1 END) AS pass_count"),
             DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN os_flash_result = 'FAIL' THEN 1 END) AS fail_count"))
    ->where("created_at", ">=", "2018-09-17")
    ->groupBy("date")
    ->get();
```

This corresponds to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    DATE(created_at) AS date,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN os_flash_result = 'PASS' THEN 1 END) AS pass_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN os_flash_result = 'FAIL' THEN 1 END) AS fail_count
FROM mobile_prod_pograms    -- should be called mobile_prod_programs
WHERE
    created_at >= '2018-09-17'
GROUP BY
    date;
```

Comment: Well this is just brilliant,this what i was looking for.

Comment: FYI - you can use `selectRaw` to avoid repeated calls to `DB::raw()` and you could use MySQLs quirk where it evaluates booleans as `1` or `0` to the following effect - `selectRaw("DATE(created_at) AS date, SUM(os_flash_result = 'PASS') AS passCount, SUM(os_flash_result = 'FAIL') AS fail_count")`

Comment: @fubar Yes...I know this, but I actually prefer several separate calls to `DB::raw`, because it eliminates the chance of messing up the separating commas.  Of course, it's better to not even have to use raw SQL ever, but in this case, we may not have much of a choice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Okay. I feel the SQL is more clear than wrapping SQL in `DB:raw()`, but each to his own :)